# ReactJS adding something to database will display after refresh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, react-hooks, rendering

I connected my app to my database and at first, it fetches the data from the database and displays the result based on the values in the database.
I added a post request and handled it in the backend. When I add something to the database it will be added perfectly, but the thing is I cannot see it in the display until I refresh the page.

I created addCodeToDB function which adds the input from input field to the database and at the same time I call the fetchFromDB database to fetch the latest data to display.

I think there should be something wrong with the async behaviour, can you please tell me if I am in the right direction at all?

Here is my App.js:

```
function App() {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3001/api/codes';

  const [dataFromDB, setDataFromDB] = useState(null);

  const fetchCodesFromDB = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      setDataFromDB(data);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCodesFromDB();
  }, []);

  const addCodeToDB = async (code, percentage) => {
    try {
      await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/codes', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          code: code,
          percentage: percentage,
          status: 'active',
        }),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

and here is my component:

```
const DefineDiscount = ({ dataFromDB, addCodeToDB, fetchCodesFromDB }) => {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const code = e.target.elements['discount-code'].value.toUpperCase();
    const percentage = e.target.elements['precentage'].value;

    // Check if the code already exists in the array
    const existingCode = dataFromDB.find((item) => item.code === code);

    if (existingCode) {
      // If the code already exists, display a message and don't add it to the array
      alert('Code already exists!');
    } else {
      // If the code doesn't exist, add it to the array
      addCodeToDB(code, percentage);
      fetchCodesFromDB();
    }
  };
```

Comment: There are a couple of different ways to handle this.  You could optimistically add the data to your array in state when you make the request to database and then just revert the values if an error occurs.  Depending on your API, it may return the newly created record, which you could await and then use to update state. or you could always refetch all of the records after you create a new record.

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is here:

```
} else {
  // If the code doesn't exist, add it to the array
  addCodeToDB(code, percentage);
  fetchCodesFromDB();
}
```

Since there is no awaiting happening for the asynchronous `addCodeToDB` function - while you are adding new data to your backend, you're frontend has already fetched data again and re-rendered. The easiest way to resolve this is to call `fetchCodesFromDB` as a callback in the Promise resolve:

```
} else {
  // If the code doesn't exist, add it to the array
  addCodeToDB(code, percentage).then(fetchCodesFromDB);
}
```

Comment: i tried it but still need to refresh the page to see the change.

Comment: Does your post route resolve when the database has been updated, or immediately?